# trying to remove only string element from an array but cant loop right

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi im trying to remove only the string element from an array. I want to make a loop that checks to see if the el is a string and if it is a string it must be spliced. but right now it only removes the 1st matching element that's a string. why?

```
   var arr = [1,2, 'a', 'b']
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if(typeof arr[i] === "string"){
            var index = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
                if(index > -1){
                    arr.splice(index, 1)

                }
                console.log(arr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modifying the array in place. Let's look at your iterations.

```
(i=0, type number)
[1,2,'a','b']

(i=1, type number)
[1,2,'a','b']

(i=2, type string)
[1,2,'b'] // removed 'a' at index 2

(i=3, type string)
[1,2,'b'] // there is no 4th item
```

I recommend just using `filter()` to filter the array:

```
arr=arr.filter(function(item){return typeof item != 'string'})
```

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying the array which you're looping. So you're modifying it in run time, so that's affecting your results. You shouldn't splice an array while you're iterating through it.

You can just do the below using `Array.filter`

```
arr = arr.filter(Number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array like:

```
arr.filter(function(item){ return typeof item !== 'string';});
```

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

Answer (score 1):

The  arr.length changes when you remove an item, pushing your index 1 character ahead of where you expect to be, so you need to compensate for it. Add...

```
i--;
```

after the splice. Like this:

```
   var arr = [1,2, 'a', 'b']
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if(typeof arr[i] === "string"){
            var index = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
                if(index > -1){
                    arr.splice(index, 1)
                    i--;                    
                }
                console.log(arr);
        }
```

Comment: The arr.filter option is much better, but hopefully this helps you understand why your code wasn't working